# Error: 'shuffle' is not an exported object from 'namespace:merTools'

Tags: r, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle my dataset by row and I have found function shuffle in package merTools. The code looks like this:

```
data = merTools::shuffle(my_data)
```

but I still have this error:

```
Error: 'shuffle' is not an exported object from 'namespace:merTools'
```

even when I have tried to load the package:

```
library(merTools)
data = shuffle(my_data)
```

it is giving this error:

```
Error in shuffle(my_data) : could not find function "shuffle"
```

but I can see it in Help, that it exists.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the package does not export the function, you can try making a copy in the `.GlobalEnv` with `shuffle <- merTools:::shuffle` and then use it as you would if it were exported. (I have just did this and it worked.)

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas , yes I have version 0.5.0 . So it is confusing that I can find it in Help, but I can not use it. I will use the sample, as you recommended, thank you.

Comment: If you are loading merTools only for this function, it might not be worth it since base R does it already. It was mentionned in a previous (deleted) comment : `data[sample(nrow(data) , ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So both answers helped:

```
shuffled_data <- getFromNamespace("shuffle", "merTools")(data)
```

and this as well:

```
shuffled_data <- data[sample(nrow(data)) , ]
```

**Note:**

Both ways return the same result. This can be seen if the results are made reproducible with `set.seed`.

```
set.seed(1234)
mtc1 <- getFromNamespace("shuffle", "merTools")(mtcars)
set.seed(1234)
mtc2 <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars)), ]

identical(mtc1, mtc2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

May be it is an unexported function

```
getAnywhere("shuffle")$where
[1] "namespace:merTools"
```

The difference is that, when there is an exported function, it shows the package as well

```
getAnywhere("mutate")$where
#[1] "package:dplyr"   "namespace:plyr"  "namespace:dplyr"
```

So, we can get the function from the namespace and apply on the data

```
out <- getFromNamespace("shuffle", "merTools")(mtcars)
head(out, 5)
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.0  1  0    4    2
#Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.77 15.5  0  1    5    6
#Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.17 14.5  0  1    5    4
#Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.14 16.7  0  1    5    2
#Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.9  1  0    4    4
```

Or as @RuiBarradas suggested in the comments, for repeated usage, it may be better to assign the function exported into an identifier

```
shuffle <- getFromNamespace("shuffle", "merTools")
```

and then directly apply that

```
shuffle(mtcars)
```

Comment: Or maybe `shuffle <- getFromNamespace("shuffle", "merTools")`.